# PowerShell 5.1 using ExpandedProperty but not getting desired output

Tags: powershell

Given:
PowerShell 5.1

If I run the following:

```
Get-Service -ComputerName WKSP000D1E3F -DisplayName *bit*
```

I get this:

```
Status   Name               DisplayName                           
------   ----               -----------                           
Stopped  BDESVC             BitLocker Drive Encryption Service    
Stopped  Check Point Bit... Check Point Endpoint Security Bitlo...
```

But I want to expand both Name and DisplayName, so I do this:

```
Get-Service -ComputerName WKSP000D1E3F -DisplayName *bit* | Select -ExpandProperty Name
```

and get this:

```
BDESVC
Check Point Bitlocker Management
```

How do I get all the columns with column headers, like the first output above except without ellipses?

```
Status   Name               DisplayName                           
------   ----               -----------                           
Stopped  BDESVC             BitLocker Drive Encryption Service    
Stopped  Check Point Bit... Check Point Endpoint Security Bitlo...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `...` are just a *display* problem (the data is there in full).

If you use [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object)'s `-ExpandProperty` parameter, you by definition only get property *values*, and  since these values are *strings* in your case, that's all you get (albeit *without* truncation).

To **prevent the for-display truncation**, pipe to [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table)  **`-AutoSize`**, though note that this requires PowerShell to collect all output from the input command first, before starting to display output (see next section for alternatives).

```
Get-Service -ComputerName WKSP000D1E3F -DisplayName *bit* | Format-Table AutoSize
```

Note: Since the console (terminal) window width is always the limiting factor, `-AutoSize` can result in *fewer* columns getting displayed.

If possible, you can **exclude columns that aren't of interest**, by specifying only those that are, via `-Property` (you may omit this parameter name, becasue it is positionally implied); e.g.:

```
Get-Service -ComputerName WKSP000D1E3F -DisplayName *bit* |
  Format-Table -Property Status, Name -AutoSize
```

---

**Alternatives that avoid `-AutoSize` and its collect-everything-first behavior**:

- Use **`-Wrap`**, which doesn't *truncate*, but **uses (artificial) *line breaks*** to spread values that don't fit into the column across multiple lines.

  ```
  Get-Service -ComputerName WKSP000D1E3F -DisplayName *bit* | Format-Table -Wrap
  ```
- If you know the *maximum* width of a column of interest ahead of time, you can **use a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties) to prescribe a column's width**; e.g.:

  ```
  Get-Service -ComputerName WKSP000D1E3F -DisplayName *bit* |
    Format-Table Status, 
                 @{ Expression='Name'; Width=40 },
                 DisplayName
  ```

Answer (score 2):

```
Get-Service -DisplayName *wmi*
```

```
Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Stopped  wmiApSrv           WMI Performance Adapter
Running  WMIRegistrationSe… Intel(R) Management Engine WMI Provid…
```

I find myself using  `| Out-GridView` if desired output isn't being shown.

```
Get-Service -DisplayName *wmi* | 
    Out-GridView
```

[Out-GridView Result](https://ibb.co/Yfg7KgD)

Alternatively, you could use `| Format-List` if you're not set on using Table View

```
Get-Service -DisplayName *wmi* | 
    Format-List
```

```
Name                : wmiApSrv
DisplayName         : WMI Performance Adapter
Status              : Stopped
DependentServices   : {}
ServicesDependedOn  : {}
CanPauseAndContinue : False
CanShutdown         : False
CanStop             : False
ServiceType         : Win32OwnProcess

Name                : WMIRegistrationService
DisplayName         : Intel(R) Management Engine WMI Provider Registration
Status              : Running
DependentServices   : {}
ServicesDependedOn  : {}
CanPauseAndContinue : False
CanShutdown         : False
CanStop             : True
ServiceType         : Win32OwnProcess
```

If you only want `Status,Name,DisplayName` headers,

```
Get-Service -DisplayName *wmi* | 
    Select-Object -Property Status, Name, DisplayName | 
        Format-List
```

```
Status      : Stopped
Name        : wmiApSrv
DisplayName : WMI Performance Adapter

Status      : Running
Name        : WMIRegistrationService
DisplayName : Intel(R) Management Engine WMI Provider Registration
```